# How do xIE, xPIE, and xPP work in handling traps and interrupts in RISC-V privileged?

Tags: interrupt-handling, riscv, instruction-set

I am new in RISC-V architecture. At present, I'm reading about RISC-V privileged in Volume II: Privileged Architecture. However, I have some concerns about the way xIE, xPIE, xPP bits work in handling traps and interrupts. Here is what the privileged Architecture spec says for these bits:

> "When a trap is taken from privilege mode y into privilege mode x, x PIE is set to the value of x IE; x IE is set to 0; and x PP is set to y."

> "When executing an x RET instruction, supposing x PP holds the value y, x IE is set to x PIE; the privilege mode is changed to y; x PIE is set to 1; and x PP is set to U."

And my questions are:

1. Are these specs used for stopping a low priority trap to execute a higher priority trap or it's stop asynchronous trap (Ex: software interrupt) to execute synchronous trap (Ex: system call)?
2. If the question 1 is true in two cases or one of them, does processor re-execute the trap that is stopped before?
3. Why xIE is always set to 0 after xPIE copies xIE value when a trap is taken and xPIE is set to 1 after xIE copies xPIE value when xRET is executed? Can you give me an example to explain this one?

Sorry for taking your time because of these questions. Hopefully someone can help me to solve them.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: this is a wrong forum for this question. we discuss programming issues here. Try 'electrical engineering'

Comment: @Serge, xIE, xIP, xPIE are all software accessible and the question is asking what cpu behavior is mandated by the standard. xuan tuan doesn't specify why they want that information, but it very well could be to support writing software. Alternatively, it would be to implement a CPU in verilog which is also valid for stackoverflow.

Comment: in any case it has nothing to do with 'verilog' or any other programming languages discussed in **this** forum.